# Calculate the amount payable to each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the amount payable to each user.
This may be in the negative. Briefly:

MustPay = AmountTaken - AmountPaid

I could not write the sql query.

```
SELECT users.Name, users.Surname,
    SUM(takenfrom.AmountTaken) - SUM(paid.AmountPaid) AS MustPay
FROM users
LEFT JOIN takenfrom ON takenfrom.UserId = users.UserId
LEFT JOIN paid ON paid.UserId = users.UserId
GROUP BY users.UserId
```

Tables:

```
FIRST TABLE USERS
| UserId   | Name | Surname |
| 1        | foo  | boo     |
| 2        | f    | b       |


SECOND TABLE TAKENFROM
| TakenFromId | UserId | AmountTaken|
| 1           | 1      | 100        |
| 2           | 2      | 200        |

THIRD TABLE PAID
| PaidId | UserId | AmountPaid|
| 1      | 2      | 50        |
| 2      | 2      | 50        |


RESULT TABLE
| Name   | Surname| MustPay   |
| foo    | boo    | 100       |
| f      | b      | 100       |
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to `JOIN` tables?  Here's a hint, you'll need a `LEFT JOIN` for `PAID`.

Comment: I tried left join. I think I should use full join in takenfrom and paid tables. But I did not succeed. @RocketHazmat

Comment: Can you show the query you tried?

Comment: SELECT users.Name, users.Surname, SUM(takenfrom.AmountTaken) - SUM(paid.AmountPaid) AS MustPay FROM users LEFT JOIN takenfrom ON takenfrom.UserId = users.UserId LEFT JOIN paid ON paid.UserId = users.UserId GROUP BY users.UserId    @RocketHazmat

Comment: Note: phpMyAdmin is just a database *client*. It has almost nothing to do with the database itself or the queries you're running. It's not relevant here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need a `LEFT JOIN` on `TakenFrom` as every user is going to have an amount billed to them, whether or not they've paid is what `Paid` is for.  You only need a `LEFT JOIN` on `Paid`, as user may have paid already or they may have not.

Since not every user is going to have an `AmountPaid`, so you need to use an `IFNULL()` to check that.  `SUM()` returns `NULL` if it's given a `NULL`.

<strike>Also, unless there are multiple rows for each user in `takenfrom`, then you don't need a `SUM()` for `AmountTaken`.</strike>

```
SELECT users.Name, users.Surname,
    SUM(takenfrom.AmountTaken) - IFNULL(SUM(paid.AmountPaid), 0) AS MustPay
FROM users
JOIN takenfrom ON takenfrom.UserId = users.UserId
LEFT JOIN paid ON paid.UserId = users.UserId
GROUP BY users.UserId
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e69b3b/1

UPDATE: If *both* `paid` and `takenfrom` have multiple rows (for a `UserId`), then you'll get duplicate rows from the `JOIN`s.  To fix this, you can use subqueries instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Name, Surname,IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(AmountTaken) FROM takenfrom WHERE UserID = users.UserID
), 0) - IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) FROM paid WHERE UserID = users.UserID
), 0) AS MustPay
FROM users
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3960b5/26

Comment: SUM(takenfrom.AmountTaken) - IFNULL(SUM(paid.AmountPaid), 0) .......   I change it. But it didn't work. For example, when I increase the paid table by 500, I think the result table will not be negative. In short, I wish the result was negative in some cases. @RocketHazmat

Comment: @ceza What "didn't work" about this?  What result that give?  What result did you expect?

Comment: @ceza I added a link to an online demo.  Try changing the demo to show what you are seeing.

Comment: I want users to collect all debts and collect all payments then I want to deduct payments from debt In this way, I want to eliminate the balance of each user. @RocketHazmat

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess I couldn't explain what I wanted to tell.

Comment: I could not add 500 to the paid table in the demo.  (3, 2, 500); @RocketHazmat

Comment: in this case the result in the mustpay table would be negative @RocketHazmat

Comment: It happened. I made an absurd mistake. Thanks. @RocketHazmat

Comment: Please

INSERT INTO takenfrom
     (`TakenFromId`,` UserId`, `AmountTaken`)
VALUES
     (1, 1, 100),
     (2, 2, 200),
     (3, 2, 100);

Can you add @RocketHazmat

Comment: f mustpay must be 200 in DEMO. but it doesn't work :( @RocketHazmat

Comment: @ceza Ok, I see the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3960b5/1

Comment: It doesn't work. In the result table should be foo 100, f 200. @@RocketHazmat

Comment: foo = 100 - 0 ;     f = 200 + 100 - (50 + 50);    @RocketHazmat

Comment: @ceza I've updated the answer with a new solution.  You'll need to use subqueries to get the values from each of the tables.

Comment: DEMO http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66c602/1/0    x: -101 can it be done?  @RocketHazmat  x is a new user and only he has been paid.

Comment: @ceza I guess you'd another `IFNULL()` around the 1st subquery, too.  Check the answer for an update.

Comment: happened. DEMO : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13dda2/1/0 Thanks for everything. UwU

Comment: Glad I could help :-)